# C++ Getting an object

Tags: c++, class, object

Lets say I have the following class:

```
static int counter = 0;

class Account {
public:
   int ID;
   int favNumber;

   Account(int favNum) {
      this->ID = ++counter;
      this->favNumber = favNum;
   }
};

Account user1(4);
Account user2(9);
```

Now both accounts user1 and user2 have different ID that is unique. Is there any way by knowing the ID of the account get the field of the object like "favNumber", if so how should it be implemented?

Something like getFieldById(int ID)

Comment: store the Account objects in a map<int, Account> and look up by the ID as a key in the map?

Comment: What you could do, is to have a class, say; Clerk, which has a create account method, which creates an account internally (adding it to a list or map) and then implement your getById function on this class (as well as a close account function obviously)

Comment: Warning: if counter is in a header file, the id may not remain unique! Why not put counter as a private static class member instead?

Comment: consider moving the `static int counter` into a private/protected field of `Account`, as it seems it is not a global counter but one for Account ID's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `std::map` to do this :

```
#include <map>

class Account {
   // Make attributes private. It is a better practice
   int ID;
   int favNumber;

   static int s_Counter;
 //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ It is better to move it as a static private member of Account

public:

   Account(int favNum) {
      this->ID = ++s_Counter;
      this->favNumber = favNum;
   }

   // GETTERS
   int GetFavNumber() const { return favNumber; }
   int GetID() const { return ID; }
};

int Account::s_Counter = 0;
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Don't forget to initialize it

Account user1(4);
Account user2(9);

std::map<int, Account*> accounts;
accounts[user1.GetID()] = &user1;
accounts[user2.GetID()] = &user2;

// To get a favNum with some id :
accounts[id]->GetFavNumber();
```

**But with this technique, be sure that the pointers are still valid ! If not, you could have bad surprises ...**

---

What we have done in this previous code ?

- We passed the attributs in private (better practice).
- We created Getters to access them.
- We passed the counter `static` variable as a `static private` member of `Account`.
- We used `std::map` to have a listing of the accounts created and the keys are the IDs of the Accounts.

Comment: It gives me an error when I use "accounts[1].GetFavNumber();"

error C2228: left of '.GetFavNumber' must have class/struct/union

Also if I try something like:
std::map<int, Account> accounts;
accounts[user1.GetID()] = user1;
accounts[user2.GetID()] = user2;
accounts[1].GetFavNumber();

it gives me error: error C2512: 'Account::Account' : no appropriate default constructor available 

I really do not know what's the problem. (Yes I created main method and added appropriate code there)

Comment: @Winten There was a mistake in my code. Change `accounts[id].GetFavNumnber();` by `accounts[id]->GetFavNumnber();`.I also edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
std::map<int, Account*>
```

to store a pointer to the accounts by their id. It's up to you to make sure the pointers remain valid. Alternatively, you could use

```
std::map<int, Account>
```

and let the map look after your accounts for you.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to central place to store all the objects that are going to be created and then search for the id there.

You could store them as

- Plain old array
  Search the entire list for your object of ID and then return the field
- ID indexed array
  array[ID] is the object you need, return the field
- Hash(`std::map`) from ID to object
  Similar syntax as ID indexed array but is a hash table lookup

Each have their pros and cons in simplicity, speed of search, memory used etc.

You could also store object pointers in the above.

To automate things, you can make the above list a `private static` member of your `Account` class, and add to it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a list and for each time you pass the constructor add the item to the list. then when a request get to your `getFieldById` search your list.

the list will have to be in a place you can search in and only be initiate once